# Python minimalmodbus reading 16-bit register

Tags: python, minimalmodbus

We have a heating controller that using 16-bit registers to read data.

Example:
register 512 - bit from 0 to 16 is using to read temperature.

This code works fine for this exmaple

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import minimalmodbus
import time

minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE = 19200

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)

while True:
    temperature1 = instrument.read_register(512, 0, 3)
    temperature2 = instrument.read_register(513, 0, 3)
    temperature3 = instrument.read_register(514, 0, 3)
    temperature4 = instrument.read_register(515, 0, 3)
```

But this controller also have 516th register with this bit table:

[image]

Can't get any data from this register. What the bit operation must be to get 'status' from this register?

I'am googling with no success for like two days. I'am not good with bit operations.

Any answers much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be possible that the register addresses you use are offsetted by 1? Meaning that register number 516 is at address 515? That would probably give you some erroneous value for `temperature4`... Just as a side note the two last arguments you give to `read_register` are not needed as that method signature reads `def read_register(self, registeraddress, number_of_decimals=0, functioncode=3, signed=False)`

Comment: I can read 512-515 registers with tempearuture wthout problem and I get real values. I have update post with new image with all registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you would like to do is get the `status`section from register 516, you could extract the bits you want with [Bitwise Operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) :

```
register516 = instrument.read_register(516)
status = (register516 >> 7) & 0x7
```

That will shift and mask the value to get the 3 desired bits corresponding to `status`.